# How can I configure multiple different destinations?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

i want to have multiple destinations is it possible to configure in cloud foundry environment?
[xs-app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upGyL.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really precise. When talking about SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry, destinations can be configured on different levels. Most importantly the question is where you want to configure them with which purpose.

I suppose your linked screenshot about the xs-app.json is related to the approuter you have deployed, and you want to configure different routes. This is the first important thing to understand. You are probably trying to deploy and configure an application that acts as an entry-point for a bigger application, maybe even a SaaS-style offering or a "simple" service. The approuter on the SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry normally acts as the browser-based gate into your application, handling SAML/IDP authentication and session management.

A destination can be seen as configured "target" for certain requests. Destinations can be configured within the Cloud Cockpit for example on subaccount level. Mostly they define the required configuration for backend systems, for example to establish connectivity to an SAP Backend (S/4 HANA or even OnPremise Systems). The approuter knows also destinations defined in its environment variables, mostly through its deployment descriptor.

I would recommend the following tutorials and documentation references for more information about destinations on the platform and the xs-app.json configuration descriptor:

https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/cp-cf-create-destination.html

https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/cp-connectivity-consume-odata-service-approuter.html

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/6ba89596e3a64a5480c3977d4ea7fdba.html
(not necessarily cloud related, but still helpful)